# How to Pass value to the custom helper.?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here I have a helper file. I am using this helper file for session login. Using this helper I can get value statically. but I want to get value dynamically. means I want to pass value from controller to helper.

here is my helper code

```
<?php
         if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

            if ( ! function_exists('get_user_details')){
                    function get_user_details($user_id){
                       //get main CodeIgniter object
                       $ci =& get_instance();

                       //load databse library
                       $ci->load->database();


                       //get data from database
                       $query = $ci->db->get_where('user_profile',array('id'=>$user_id));

                       if($query->num_rows() > 0){
                           $result = $query->row_array();

                           return $result;
                       }else{
                           return false;
                       }
                   }
            }

    ?>
```

and here is controller code

```
function index(){
$this->load->helper('login');
    $id = 1;
    get_user_details($id);

}
```

Comment: Have you done any troubleshooting?  If so, what exactly?

Answer (score 2):

In your `controller` try like this..

```
function index(){
$this->load->helper('login');
    $id = 1;
    $data = get_user_details($id);
    if($count($data)>0)
      {
        print_r($data); //prints array of records 
      }
    else{
        echo "No record found!!";
      }

}
```